# Python math domain error: d1 = math.log(stock_price[t]/S0)/(vol*(time**0.5))+0.5*vol*(time**0.5)

Tags: python

everyone. I just got a problem when I want to calculate the delta of Black-Scholes Euro-call option. The script I wrote is here:

```
    stock_price = np.zeros(252)
    profit = np.zeros(252)
    stock_price[0] += S0
    profit[0] = -call
    delta_new = np.zeros(252)
    delta_new[0] = delta
    stock_price[t] = stock_price[t-1]*correlation*math.exp(vol*np.random.normal(0,1))
    time = T-t
    d1 = math.log(stock_price[t]/S0)/(vol*(time**0.5))+0.5*vol*(time**0.5)
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Ensure that the arg of `math.log()` is never <= 0.

Comment: When I run, the line I calculate stock_price[t] always show math domain error. I have make sure the log number is between(0,1]. I'm not sure which math function in this line lead to this error?

Comment: Why not split it across more lines, do some debugging and find out?

Comment: If `S0` is ever 0, then you'll be taking the log of `np.InF` check that you're not dividing by 0.

Answer (score 0):

guys. I finally solved it. I was intended to simulate 10000 paths of stock prices and see their price at day 252 and also calculate their PnL. The mistake I made was that I didn't reset the t, so that the stock_price[t] can be 0 and the log can't be used.